# STL - Copy mixing containers

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to understand STL algorithms.

Copy is defined as :

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result )
```

Can some one please explain why does the following works when vectors & deques are mixed but fails when vectors and sets are mixed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int myints[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
  vector<int> myvector;
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  set<int> mset(myints,myints+8);
  set<int>::iterator setItr = mset.begin();




  deque<int> deq;
  deq.resize(10);
  deque<int>::iterator deqItr = deq.begin();
  myvector.resize(7);   // allocate space for 7 elements
  copy ( myints, myints+7, myvector.begin() );

  copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), deqItr );
  cout << "deque contains:";
  for (deque<int>::iterator dit=deq.begin(); dit!=deq.end(); ++dit)
    cout << " " << *dit;

  cout << endl;

  //copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), setItr );


  return 0;
}
```

I understand vectors/deque have random access iterators,  where as set's have bidirectional iterators. I fail to understand why compilation fails when only a input/output iterators are required.

PS : This is just an experiment to increase my understanding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associative containers (in plain C++03) are special containers that keep their elements sorted at all times, commonly implemented as a Red Black Tree. To maintain the order invariant, the set and map iterators provide constant references into the key object, and as such you cannot modify it.

In particular for `std::set<T>`, the iterator will usually be such that `std::iterator_traits< std::set<T>::iterator >::reference` is `const T&`, and as such the assignment implicit in the `std::copy` operation will fail.

If what you want to do is insert the elements into a set, you can use iterators from the `<iterator>` header that will perform `insert` operations in the set:

```
std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter( s, s.end() ) ); // s is the set
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , it makes sense due to the ordering problem.

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` and `std::deque` have a way to preallocate space. `std::set` doesn't. Without preallocating the space, attempting to dereference the iterator you pass to `copy` produces undefined behavior.

The obvious alternative is to use insert iterators instead -- though, unfortunately, you still <strike>need</strike>nearly always use different code for a set than a deque or vector:

```
std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::back_inserter(mydeque));

std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::inserter(mySet, mySet.end());
```

Comment: You don't really need different code, the second approach will work both for a `set` and a `deque` (or `vector`, `list`...): `std::copy( src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter( dst, dst.end()) );` can be used with both.

Comment: I fail to understand why is pre-allocation required. Is this to avoid bugs due to passing iterators where no memory is allocated ? ex: if i were to remove the resize and pass it to copy, it does end up as a seg fault.  i.e. pre-allocation did not help. Am i missing something?

Comment: @David: You're right -- "need" was the wrong word. "Nearly always use" would be more accurate.

Comment: @Ricko M: I was referring to the fact that you were using `resize` to make space in the vector/deque, but set doesn't provide a resize.

Answer (score 0):

It works for vector and deque because you can allocate space beforehand. With other containers, like map, you need an iterator adapter to do that for you. Look at insert_iterator, for example.